# union all on the fields just giving me only one column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running the query where i need two separate counts, but it is showing under one column.

any idea how can i fix it

```
SELECT
         count(*) as x
        FROM
          tblpost
     
        WHERE
          tblpost.PostStatusID = 6
       
        UNION ALL 
          SELECT
         count(*) as y
        FROM
          tblpost
          
        WHERE
          tblpost.PostStatusID = 7
```

i want it to display x and column and y as a column but only 1 row with two columns, using mysql 5.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want a `UNION`, you want a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT x, y
  FROM (SELECT count(*) as x
          FROM tblpost
          WHERE tblpost.PostStatusID = 6) z
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT count(*) as y
                FROM tblpost
                WHERE tblpost.PostStatusID = 7) zz
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f80240023186fe9d5fed1a92d3826f2e)